# echo out message after redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, echo

I have a button on users profiles that allows another user to add a user to their favorites.
Once this button is clicked they are linked to the sql process file favorite.php.

Once the sql script has run it links the user back to the original profile page which is profile.php.

now what i want to do is find out how i can echo a message on the page profile.php after the sql has completed. I've tried the following but nothing happens.

can someone please show me what i'd need to do to get this working? thank you

favorite.php:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');

session_start();

    confirm_logged_in();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

header("Location: profile.php?id=" . $user_to_id['user_id'] . "added=1");


?>
```

profile.php:

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['added']) && $_GET['added'] == 1) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">This user was successfully added to your favorites.</div>"; ?>

            <? } ?>
```

Comment: i can add my security later, when the code actually works, security is no good if the code doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Your redirected URL will look like this:

```
 profile.php?id=123456added=1
 #                   ^
```

Notice the missing `&` in the parameters. Adapt your `header()` call and include it before the `"added=1"` concat.

```
 header("Location: profile.php?id=" . $user_to_id['user_id'] . "&added=1");
 #                                                              ^
```

On a related note, you would have found out earlier if it wasn't for that `isset`:

```
 if (isset($_GET['added']) && $_GET['added'] == 1) {
```

Leave it out, as this is a required param and you *want to get a note* for such occassions. Instead just turn of notices/warnings on your production server.

Comment: sorry i dont understand, could you please give me an example?

Comment: ok i thought that was what you meant. i did that and i still don't get a message echoed out on the page.

Comment: Well, not enough context. What does `print_r($_REQUEST)` say? When is `$message` printed out?

Comment: it says this: Array ( [id] => 5 [PTBheadlogo] => 4 [PHPSESSID] => b43eda2a3dd44bec91acaed42cec7845 )